# Three.js make object3d child expand to fill its parents boundaries

Tags: javascript, three.js

Let's say I have 2 object3ds, one is nested inside the other:

```
var object_1 = new THREE.Object3D();
var object_2 = new THREE.Object3D();
object_1.add( object_2 );
```

Let's say object_1 is AxB units wide. How can I tell object_2 to have that size? In other words, how can I tell the object_2 to expand its size until it reaches its parents size?

---

### **UPDATE**

Thanks for the refference, it helped.
This is how I got parents size:

```
// parents model    
model.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
var object_width = model.geometry.boundingBox.max.x - model.geometry.boundingBox.min.x;
var object_height = model.geometry.boundingBox.max.y - model.geometry.boundingBox.min.y;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THREE.Geometry` objects have bounding-box methods and values. If you know the relative sizes of the unscaled gemetric elements, then you can apply `object_2.scale.set(x,y,z)` where those parameters are the relative differences in bounds between `object_1.geometry` and `object_2.geometry` -- but *only* if these objects are simple meshes. If they have more complex or dynamic shapes, well... you haven't provided enough information detail here to give a more specific answer.